# Adding cookie message with the privacy pack to blogdown website

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I would like to add a cookie message to inform readers that my blog is using cookies. I am using hugo blogdown with the "tranquilpeak" theme. Unfortunately, this theme doesn't have the privacy pack implemented yet, so I tried to add the infos which are used in the "academic" theme from this [site](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/commit/c22d653c43149f911101ea3d2bb0fb30853e355e). I added:

```
privacy_pack = true
```

to "config.toml". Created the "cookie_consent.html" file with

```
{{ if .Site.Params.privacy_pack }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js">        
</script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    window.cookieconsent.initialise({
      "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#000"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#f1d600"
    }
  },
  "content": {
    "message": {{ i18n "cookie_message" | default "This website uses cookies to ensure you get the best experience on our website." }},
    "dismiss": {{ i18n "cookie_dismiss" | default "Got it!" }},
    "link": {{ i18n "cookie_learn" | default "Learn more" }}
       }
})});
    </script>
     {{ end }}
```

and than I added:

```
 {{ partial "cookie_consent.html" . }}
```

to the file "header.html". Unfortunately the cookie statement is not showing up and I don't know where to start searching for the reason. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi ... just wondering ... have you checked in console / developer tools that the script src loaded and wasnt blocked by your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, [Maateen](https://github.com/maateen) pointed out that one can use the [Cookie Consent JavaScript plugin](https://github.com/osano/cookieconsent).

You can visit this link and generate your own codes. However, for a quick workaround, you can copy the following codes and paste them at the end of *"foot_end.html"* of your theme.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.js" data-cfasync="false"></script>
<script>
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#2D2D39"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#14a7d0"
    }
  },
  "theme": "edgeless",
  "position": "bottom-right",
  "content": {
      "message": "This website uses cookies for Google Analytics so that I know how many people are reading the blog and which blogposts are the most popular. The website does not collect any personal data.",
  "href": "https://www.cookiesandyou.com/"
  }
});
</script>
```

To see a demo of this code, you may visit my [blog](https://philippgaertner.github.io/)